# Schema.org MedicalClinic

Tags: seo, google, bing, google-plus

I'm using http://schema.org/MedicalClinic on main page of my client's site. I've filled in as many as I can including address,name, url, image url, geolocation, descripition, opening hours, specialty etc.

It's coming up ok when I test it on Richsnippet tool but I don't know what benefits I can get from using it.

I don't see anything on the search result pages on Google.

What should I expect from it? Would the image show up on the SERP? If so, wouldn't it be similar to what you would get with Publisher meta tag and Google Plus as it also allows you to get Google Plus image appearing on the SERP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the highest level, you [should never "expect" anything](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-rich-snippets#noshow), given there's no guarantee that microdata will even be used if discovered.

Specific to your question, though, this is not one of the [documented suported types](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1088474&parent=21997&ctx=topic), so barring some other specialized search engine, at the moment Google doesn't appear to even be looking for this flavor of microdata, much less giving you any benefits from it.

Comment: Just to add to this answer - I have microdata on my site for musical albums and musical performers, things that I would think are mainstream. None of the search engines seem to do anything with this data.